OpenVPN upgrade from 2.5.6 to 2.6.12, removed option key-method 2, IOS device not able to connect after that
I'm new to openvpn and trying to upgrade openvpn from 2.5.6 to 2.6.12. Key-method 2 option is deprecated (correction - key-method 2 option is removed) in 2.5 version, so  I have removed the option from server.conf file, now I'm not able to connect vpn in IOS device, however Android device can still connect with the below mentioned configuration. Please help me to identify alternate to key-method 2.
Below is server.conf file
dev tun
dev-node VPNT
topology subnet
port 8114
proto udp
persist-key 
persist-tun 
server  10.1.0.224 255.255.255.224
keepalive 60 300
plugin "C:\\tls-plugin.dll"
log-append "C:\\ProgramData\\VPN\\log4c.conf"
status "C:\\ProgramData\\VPN\\vpn-status.log" 47
ca "C:\\ProgramData\\VPN\\ca.crt"
cert "C:\\ProgramData\\VPN\\server.crt"
key "C:\\ProgramData\\VPN\\server.key"
tls-auth "C:\\ProgramData\\VPN\\TA.key"
auth SHA256
dh "C:\\ProgramData\\VPN\\dh2048.pem"
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp "
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
comp-lzo 
management 127.0.0.1 56834
tls-timeout 3
cipher AES-256-CBC
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-CBC-SHA256


#BEGIN_CUSTOM_SETTINGS

verb 6

#END_CUSTOM_SETTINGS

Following error is reported on VPN server.
 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
TLS Error: TLS handshake failed

Update - Added vpn server logs
INFO      -  us=126813 Connection Attempt MULTI: multi_create_instance called

INFO      -  us=143839 20.163.82.254:44443 Re-using SSL/TLS context

INFO      -  us=159135 20.163.82.254:44443 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication

INFO      -  us=169353 20.163.82.254:44443 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication

INFO      -  us=178972 20.163.82.254:44443 Control Channel MTU parms [ mss_fix:0 max_frag:0 tun_mtu:1250 tun_max_mtu:0 headroom:126 payload:1600 tailroom:126 ET:0 ]

INFO      -  us=188714 20.163.82.254:44443 Data Channel MTU parms [ mss_fix:0 max_frag:0 tun_mtu:1500 tun_max_mtu:1600 headroom:136 payload:1768 tailroom:562 ET:0 ]

INFO      -  us=197991 20.163.82.254:44443 UDPv6 READ [414] from [AF_INET6]::ffff:20.163.82.254:44443: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 pid=[ #3 ] [ ] pid=2 DATA len=360

ERROR     -  us=207319 20.163.82.254:44443 TLS Error: Unroutable control packet received from [AF_INET6]::ffff:20.163.82.254:44443 (si=3 op=P_CONTROL_V1)

INFO      -  us=216408 20.163.82.254:44443 LINK packet from [248.127.0.0/234] destined for [UNKNOWN]

INFO      -  us=225025 20.163.82.254:44443 UDPv6 READ [62] from [AF_INET6]::ffff:20.163.82.254:44443: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 pid=[ #4 ] [ 0 ] DATA len=0

ERROR     -  us=234432 20.163.82.254:44443 TLS Error: Unroutable control packet received from [AF_INET6]::ffff:20.163.82.254:44443 (si=3 op=P_ACK_V1)

INFO      -  us=243417 20.163.82.254:44443 LINK packet from [248.127.0.0/234] destined for [UNKNOWN]

INFO      -  us=107467 20.163.82.254:44443 UDPv6 READ [66] from [AF_INET6]::ffff:20.163.82.254:44443: P_CONTROL_HARD_RESET_CLIENT_V2 kid=0 pid=[ #2 ] [ 0 ] pid=1 DATA len=0

INFO      -  us=125086 20.163.82.254:44443 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET6]::ffff:20.163.82.254:44443, sid=2575aee9 aa84ea47

ERROR     -  us=136820 20.163.82.254:44443 TLS Error: reading acknowledgement record from packet

INFO      -  us=146739 20.163.82.254:44443 LINK packet from [248.127.0.0/234] destined for [UNKNOWN]

INFO      -  us=156332 20.163.82.254:44443 UDPv6 WRITE [54] to [AF_INET6]::ffff:20.163.82.254:44443: P_CONTROL_HARD_RESET_SERVER_V2 kid=0 pid=[ #1 ] [ ] pid=0 DATA len=0

INFO      -  us=165324 20.163.82.254:44443 UDPv6 READ [414] from [AF_INET6]::ffff:20.163.82.254:44443: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 pid=[ #3 ] [ ] pid=2 DATA len=360

INFO      -  us=174284 20.163.82.254:44443 LINK packet from [248.127.0.0/234] destined for [UNKNOWN]

INFO      -  us=182455 20.163.82.254:44443 UDPv6 WRITE [62] to [AF_INET6]::ffff:20.163.82.254:44443: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 pid=[ #2 ] [ 2 ] DATA len=0

INFO      - us=111245 20.163.82.254:44443 UDPv6 READ [66] from [AF_INET6]::ffff:20.163.82.254:44443: P_CONTROL_HARD_RESET_CLIENT_V2 kid=0 pid=[ #2 ] [ 0 ] pid=1 DATA len=0

INFO      - us=126077 20.163.82.254:44443 PID_ERR replay-window backtrack occurred [1] [TLS_WRAP-0] [22_] 1729584337:3 1729584337:2 t=1729584342[0] r=[-2,64,15,1,1] sl=[61,3,64,528]

INFO      - us=140830 20.163.82.254:44443 PID_ERR replay [1] [TLS_WRAP-0] [22_] 1729584337:3 1729584337:2 t=1729584342[0] r=[-2,64,15,1,1] sl=[61,3,64,528]

ERROR     - us=151114 20.163.82.254:44443 Authenticate/Decrypt packet error: bad packet ID (may be a replay): [ #2 / time = (1729584337) 03:05:37 ] -- see the man page entry for --no-replay and --replay-window for more info or silence this warning with --mute-replay-warnings

ERROR     - us=161576 20.163.82.254:44443 TLS Error: incoming packet authentication failed from [AF_INET6]::ffff:20.163.82.254:44443

INFO      - us=170483 20.163.82.254:44443 LINK packet from [248.127.0.0/234] destined for [UNKNOWN]

INFO      - us=179701 20.163.82.254:44443 UDPv6 READ [414] from [AF_INET6]::ffff:20.163.82.254:44443: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 pid=[ #3 ] [ ] pid=2 DATA len=360

INFO      - us=189622 20.163.82.254:44443 PID_ERR replay [0] [TLS_WRAP-0] [22_] 1729584337:3 1729584337:3 t=1729584342[0] r=[-2,64,15,1,1] sl=[61,3,64,528]

ERROR     -  us=302573 20.163.82.254:44443 TLS Error: incoming packet authentication failed from [AF_INET6]::ffff:20.163.82.254:44443

INFO      -  us=319106 20.163.82.254:44443 LINK packet from [248.127.0.0/234] destined for [UNKNOWN]

ERROR     -  us=757727 20.163.82.254:44443 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)

ERROR     -  us=778504 20.163.82.254:44443 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed

INFO      - us=796896 20.163.82.254:44443 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, client-instance restarting


Impossible. key-method was removed because it introduced a vulnerability into OpenVPN. It was removed for good.
Also it was only used for compatibility with ancient (pre-2.0) versions, so you probably never needed it at all. I, for instance, never used it, but my Apple gadgets still work perfectly, so I can certify there is certainly no need.
Also, it was not deprecated, but removed in version 2.5 (at least, man openvpn of the version 2.5.1 says that).
Upgrade your clients, or, maybe, update their configurations so that they don't depend on this option.
Another option that you use, which is deprecated, made no-op and that will be removed, is comp-lzo. Compression makes encryption vulnerable. I suggest you to remove it too to not get caught into similar situation in the future.

Thank you @Nikita for the response. I have updated the question ( key-method 2 is removed not deprecated) I will review the client config and recheck again. Thank you

Added vpn server logs (ip and other info changed). IOS using openvpn client version 3.0 and openvpn server version is 2.6.12, is there any known compatibility between these two.  Iwas going through the available articles on internet, but I'm not able to get find any relevant information. Any pointers will be helpful
